# AJAX script does not "see" loaded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a jQuery script that loads content when a user clicks on various links on the page:

```
$('.main-navigation a[href*=\''+window.location.hostname+'\'], .site-info a[href*=\''+window.location.hostname+'\'], .widget-area a[href*=\''+window.location.hostname+'\'], #breadcrumbs a, #smi-logo a').click(function(event) 

{
// Load content and play some animaion
}
```

The problem is, some of the links (`.widget-area a[href*=\''+window.location.hostname+'\'], #breadcrumbs a`) that are supposed to be targeted by AJAX are actually **inside the loaded content**, and the script doesn't "see" them (I guess because they do not appear in the page HTML source).

How do I access those links that inside the loaded content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want delegated event handling.  Take whatever the container is that will eventually hold the dynamically loaded content (but which itself currently exists) and set your event handler on that with [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

So if it were a div with an id of, say, `foo`, you would do this:

```
var hostName = window.location.hostname;
$('#foo').on('click', 'a[href*=\''+ hostName +'\'], #breadcrumbs a', function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you, @Adam! This solved it. May I ask you to also take a look at a related question, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885808/ajax-behavior-disables-some-of-the-default-behavior

Comment: @Figaro - glad to help.  I'm afraid I don't have an answer on your other question.  I would just start removing more and more and more stuff until you can isolate what's causing your problem.  Sorry I can't be of more help on that :)

Comment: Thanks, @Adam, I'll do what you suggested.